# Windows 8, keyboard mouse stopped working

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

My keyboard mouse no longer responds necessitating that I use an external mouse.  I can not find the setting to turn it back on.  How can I re-activate this feature?

Comment: So you have a laptop with a touchpad.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You've probably accidentally disabled the Touchpad.

Re-enable it by holding <kbd>Fn</kbd> and pressing the function key with the touchpad symbol. Eg:

[image]